# Why does selecting a special vehicle have an "are you sure?" prompt?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

When I go to a garage and bring up the special car list (PS3 d-pad right), and then select a car, I get an "are you sure?" prompt.  This makes me think that it's not a choice I should make lightly.

**What is gta5 protecting me from when it asks if I am sure I want to select a special vehicle?**

Answer (score 1):

When I entered the garage once with a SUV and get out of garage with another special vehicle, I did not see the SUV later when I returned to the garage.

I have done it only once. May be that prompt is a warning as you are going to lose your current vehicle or what I have experienced is a bug.